# line-height on text with minimum 2 lines of text

Tags: css, height, line

is there a way for me to add `line-hight:22px;` 
to any texts that has two lines or more.
but not affect text that does not go onto a second line ?

Is there a way to achive this in css only ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can with pure CSS, but beware of IE8 and below. Here is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-first-line).

```
.class {
    line-height: 22px;
}

.class::first-line {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

What this does it set everything to a `line-height` of 22px, but resets the first line to a `line-height` of 1, you could also use 100% etc. That should do what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: No problem, it's quite a helpful CSS only workaround.

Comment: @andrelange91, This is brilliant but it set's different `Line-height`s for the first line and the following lines of a text with multiple lines!!